# How to stop service in a batch file and not show the cmd window

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I have a batch file where I need to stop a service before launching an application, but the cmd window popping up I think is interfering with the application starting. Is there a way to stop the service in the background without a window popping up?

```
@echo off
net stop HIP
start /wait "C:\Program Files\APP\Prog\Scan.exe"
net start HIP
```

Comment: Why is used `start /wait` on the third command line. The *Windows Command Processor* waits by default always for self-termination of an executable started during processing of a batch file. Otherwise the execution of `net stop HIP` being in real the execution of `%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe stop HIP` would not work as expected by you. It would be better to use the fully qualified file name twice also for the [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) __NET__.

Comment: The console window opened by the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) called by `explorer.exe` on double clicking on a batch file for execution of `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` with its option `/c` and the fully qualified batch file name enclosed in `"` is definitely not a problem here.

Comment: The console window opened by `CreateProcess` called by `cmd.exe` for running `C:\Program Files\APP\Prog\Scan.exe` as separate process with its own console window, standard input, output and error handles on being a console application and waiting for self-termination of this executable is definitely also not a problem. I would not use the command __NET__ to start and stop a service. The command __SC__ being with fully qualified file name `%SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe` should be used preferred for starting/stopping services.

Comment: It could be that the service `HIP` can be stopped/started only on batch file respectively `cmd.exe` processing the batch file is __run as administrator__ for having the necessary elevated privileges to stop/start this service. Change the second line to `%SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe stop HIP`, the third line to `"C:\Program Files\APP\Prog\Scan.exe"` (uses console and the standard streams of `cmd`) or `start "Scanner" "C:\Program Files\APP\Prog\Scan.exe"` (runs parallel and `cmd` continues batch file processing immediately), and fourth line to `%SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe start HIP`.

Comment: @Mofi Thanks the .bat is running much smoother following the advice in your last comment.